# SQLite Database: Unable to get specific entry data

Tags: database, sqlite, get

I'm following a tutorial about setting up SQLite database with Android Java. I've created a database and a simple table to contain data about food and its calories.  I've setup a few buttons with functions to enter data, view, get information about a specific entry, modify and delete it.

All works well except the button to get a specific entry. When I click on the 'Get Information' button, it's supposed to return with the food name and its calories value, according to the row ID I put.

Can anyone help to look at my code here, to check what's wrong or missing?

Here is the code for the classes. I've excluded some parts which are not related.
Creating the database:

```
public class FormDatabase 
{
public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_FOOD = "food_name";
public static final String KEY_CALORIE = "food_calories";

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Calories";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "FoodTable";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2; 

private DbHelper ourHelper;
private final Context ourContext;
private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{

    public DbHelper(Context context) 
    {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + 
        KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , " + 
        KEY_FOOD + " TEXT NOT NULL , " + 
        KEY_CALORIE + " TEXT NOT NULL);"        
        );
    }

public String getFood(long l) throws SQLException{
    // get data of food name
    String[] columns = new String[]{ KEY_ROWID, KEY_FOOD, KEY_CALORIE};
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, KEY_ROWID + "=" + l, null, null, null, null);
    if (c != null){
        c.moveToFirst();
        String food = c.getString(1);
        return food;
    }
    return null;
}

public String getCalorie(long l) throws SQLException{
    // get data of food calorie
    String[] columns = new String[]{ KEY_ROWID, KEY_FOOD, KEY_CALORIE};
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, KEY_ROWID + "=" + 
l, null, null, null, null);
    if (c != null){
        c.moveToFirst();
        String calorie = c.getString(2);
        return calorie;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Another class for setting the main page:

```
public class DatabaseMain extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

Button sqlUpdate, sqlView, sqlModify, sqlGetInfo, sqlDelete;
EditText sqlFood, sqlCalorie, sqlRow;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.database_main);
    sqlUpdate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSQLUpdate);
    sqlFood = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etSQLFood);
    sqlCalorie = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etSQLCalorie);

    sqlView = (Button) findViewById (R.id.bSQLopenView);
    sqlView.setOnClickListener(this);
    sqlUpdate.setOnClickListener(this);

    sqlRow = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etSQLrowInfo);
    sqlModify = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSQLmodify);
    sqlGetInfo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bgetInfo);
    sqlDelete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSQLdelete);
    sqlDelete.setOnClickListener(this);
    sqlModify.setOnClickListener(this);
    sqlDelete.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void onClick(View arg0) 
{
    // When click on buttons, data entry into database, view, modify and 
delete row
    switch (arg0.getId())
    {
case R.id.bgetInfo:
        try {
        String s = sqlRow.getText().toString();
        long l = Long.parseLong(s);
        FormDatabase foodcal = new FormDatabase(this);
        foodcal.open();
        String returnedFood = foodcal.getFood(l);
        String returnedCalories = foodcal.getCalorie(l);
        foodcal.close();

        sqlFood.setText(returnedFood);
        sqlCalorie.setText(returnedCalories);

        }catch (Exception e) 
        {           
            String error = e.toString();
            Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
            d.setTitle("This is an error!");
            TextView tv = new TextView(this);
            tv.setText(error);
            d.setContentView(tv);
            d.show();
        }

        break;
 }
}
```

The database_main layout xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width ="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:text="Food"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etSQLFood"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text" >
</EditText>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:text="Food Calorie"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</TextView>    

<EditText
     android:id="@+id/etSQLCalorie"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:inputType="number" >
 </EditText>

<Button 
    android:text="Update SQLite Database"
    android:id="@+id/bSQLUpdate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</Button>

<Button 
    android:text="View"
    android:id="@+id/bSQLopenView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</Button>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:text="Enter Row ID"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</TextView>    

 <EditText
     android:id="@+id/etSQLrowInfo"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:inputType="number" >
     <requestFocus></requestFocus>         
 </EditText>

 <Button 
    android:text="Get Information"
    android:id="@+id/bgetInfo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</Button>

<Button 
    android:text="Edit Entry"
    android:id="@+id/bSQLmodify"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</Button>

<Button 
    android:text="Delete Entry"
    android:id="@+id/bSQLdelete"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What error are you getting or is it doing nothing?

Comment: No error there, it just doing nothing. When i click on the 'Get Information' button, the data from SQLite database supposed to appear in the textView area.

Comment: add a check to to your switch statement in the onClick handler to make sure it is being fired and what object is firing it.

Comment: oh..but how to add a check ya? maybe you can suggest me..sorry that i'm quite new to this, and thanks for your input :)

Comment: Oh i found where my problem is. The GetInformation doesnt work is because my foodcal.close() is located before the display. So i moved it to the last, and it works. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to add a check to your switch statement, add a default case:

```
switch (arg0.getId())
{
    case R.id.bgetInfo:
         ... do something...
         break;
    default:
         //this will handle everything else
         // write out the argument for debugging, eg:
         Console.WriteLine(arg0.getId().ToString());
         break;
}
```

this will tell you what is coming through. if arg0.getId() is not R.id.bgetInfo, the event won't fire...

Answer (score 0):

```
Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, KEY_ROWID + "=" + 
l, null, null, null, null);
```

instead using above statement use this one

```
 Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, KEY_ROWID + "=?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(l) }, null, null, null, null);
```